# Mogodb aggregate group by then conditional sum using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a member collection with below sample data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50f6632d89862009f4c80e0f"), "_Ten" : ObjectId("50f6632d89862009f4c80e0e"), "active" : true, "role" : "Administrator", "_t" : "User" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50fe895678415503d022945f"), "_Ten" : ObjectId("50f6632d89862009f4c80e0e"), "active" : true, "role" : "Contributor", "_t" : "User" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51013a6c7841550820ad7945"), "_Ten" : ObjectId("51013a6c7841550820ad7944"), "active" : true, "role" : "Administrator", "_t" : "User" }
```

I need to find the sum of different type of users group by "_Ten"
I have wrote the following query in robomongo and got the result

```
db.getCollection('Member').aggregate( 
        [
            {
                $match:
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "active": true
                        },
                        {
                            "_t": "User"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "$group":
                {
                    "_id": "$_Ten",
                    "administrators":
                    {
                        "$sum":
                        {
                            "$cond": [
                                {
                                    $eq: ["$role", "Administrator"]
                                }, 1, 0]
                        }
                    },
                    "contributers":
                    {
                        "$sum":
                        {
                            "$cond": [
                                {
                                    $eq: ["$role", "Contributor"]
                                }, 1, 0]
                        }
                    },
                    "visitors":
                    {
                        "$sum":
                        {
                            "$cond": [
                                {
                                    $eq: ["$role", "Visitor"]
                                }, 1, 0]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
)
```

But I need the result using c#, so in c# I tried the following

```
criteriaFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("active", true);
        query = query & criteriaFilter;

        criteriaFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_t", "User");
        query = query & criteriaFilter;

        criteriaFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In<ObjectId>("_Ten", tenantIds.Select(tenantId => new ObjectId(tenantId)));
        query = query & criteriaFilter;

        var results = memberCollection.Aggregate()
                                    .Match(query)
                                    .Group(BsonDocument.Parse("{ \"$group\" : { \"_id\" : \"$_Ten\", \"administrators\" : { \"$sum\" : { \"$cond\": [{ $eq: [ \"$role\", \"Administrator\"]}, 1, 0]}}, \"contributers\" : { \"$sum\" : { \"$cond\": [{ $eq: [ \"$role\", \"Contributor\"]}, 1, 0]}},    \"visitors\" : { \"$sum\" : { \"$cond\": [{ $eq: [ \"$role\", \"Visitor\"]}, 1, 0]}}}}"))
                                    .ToList();
```

which give an error "Command aggregate failed: The field '$group' must be an accumulator object"

I need help to create c# query for my mongo query which mentioned above.

Comment: Solved the problem, tried the following and it worked
var results = memberCollection.Aggregate()                                      .Match(query).Group(new BsonDocument(){ { "_id", "$_Ten" },                                           { "administrators", new BsonDocument("$sum", new BsonDocument("$cond", BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>("[{ $eq: [ \"$role\", \"Administrator\"]}, 1, 0]") ))}
                                        }).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem, by using the following code to convert my mongo query in c#

```
var results = memberCollection.Aggregate()
.Match(query)
.Group(new BsonDocument()
{
{ "_id", "$_Ten" },
{ "administrators",
new BsonDocument(
"$sum",
new BsonDocument("$cond", BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>("[{ $eq: [ 
\"$role\", \"Administrator\"]}, 1, 0]") ))},
{ "contributors",
new BsonDocument(
"$sum",
new BsonDocument("$cond", BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>("[{ $eq: [ 
\"$role\", \"Contributor\"]}, 1, 0]") ))},
{ "visitors",
new BsonDocument(
"$sum",
new BsonDocument("$cond", BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>("[{ $eq: [ 
\"$role\", \"Visitor\"]}, 1, 0]") ))}
}).ToList();
```